# The minimal polynomial of ${\alpha}$ and ${\frac{1}{\alpha}}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Hi Im asking this question here because I couldn't find any resources online that answer this question specifically.

If say both ${\alpha}$ and ${\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ are algebraic integers then do their minimal polynomials share the same degree?

I have a feeling that this must be true although I do not know how to begin proving/disproving this claim. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$ has $\alpha$ as a root, then $a_0x^n+\cdots+a_n$ has $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ as a root. Therefore their minimal polynomials must have the same degree.

Comment: What's the name of the theorem in your first sentence?